# Error handling ResendRequest: failed to parse message (Expected CheckSum, Received CheckSum)

Tags: quickfixj

While session works overall, for one specific message we are getting checksum error.
Server is asking to resend the message and then fails with checksum validation.

```
20200729-08:03:12.189: Created session: FIXT.1.1:TEST1->TEST2
20200729-08:03:12.564: Configured socket addresses for session: [/host1:51641, /host2:51642]
20200729-08:03:12.845: MINA session created: local=/host3:60584, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketSession, remote=/host1:51641
20200729-08:03:13.970: Initiated logon request
20200729-08:03:14.017: Setting DefaultApplVerID (1137=9) from Logon
20200729-08:03:14.048: Logon contains ResetSeqNumFlag=Y, resetting sequence numbers to 1
20200729-08:03:14.048: Received logon
20200729-08:19:47.751: Received ResendRequest FROM: 36 TO: 38
20200729-08:19:47.751: Error handling ResendRequest: failed to parse message (Expected CheckSum=70, Received CheckSum=71 in 8=FIXT.1.19=44635=AE34=3649=TEST152=20200729-08:19:46.14256=TEST215=JPY30=XOFF31=101.0780000032=5000000000.00000423=1487=1570=N571=FI-C-G5371117-20200729T091945.767574=9828=0854=01003=TAlmeKYeBA1041=0VBOND0V5371117V53711171430=O25011=ECHO25014=5000000000.0000025015=JPY552=254=229=4453=2448=LIOR75625447=N452=1448=LIOR75625447=N452=6354=1453=1448=FIO1CHULC69447=N452=17448=XOFF10=071): 8=FIXT.1.19=44635=AE34=3649=TEST152=20200729-08:19:46.14256=TEST215=JPY30=XOFF31=101.0780000032=5000000000.00000423=1487=1570=N571=FI-C-G5371117-20200729T091945.767574=9828=0854=01003=TAlmeKYeBA1041=0VBOND0V5371117V53711171430=O25011=ECHO25014=5000000000.0000025015=JPY552=254=229=4453=2448=LIOR75625447=N452=1448=LIOR75625447=N452=6354=1453=1448=FIO1CHULC69447=N452=17448=XOFF10=071
```

The issue is that both messages are exactly the same and checksum difference is always 1. Any idea what could be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: This could happen for example when you got any characters on the message which are not in the ISO-8859-1 or US-ASCII charset. Are there fields on the message where a user can enter free form text? If yes, check these fields for unexpected characters. Which charset are you using for your application? Maybe UTF-8 or 16? If yes, make sure that you set that accordingly via `CharsetSupport`. However, please note that this does not adhere to the FIX standard and your counterparty needs to support this, otherwise they will run into the same checksum problem.

Comment: You could look up the exact representation of the message in question in the message store. The message might appear differently in the log file due to non-printable characters or the like.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: hi Chris, no, it was delegated to another team which was responsible for this piece of code and they removed fields what were added before and the issue gone. So it was definitely caused by few concrete fields being added, but there was noting wrong with those fields at a glance. I opened log (logged broken message) with sublime, non-printable characters should be visible but there were none. Root cause is unclear